# Got gdbm error: (13, 'Permission denied') — Despite posix permissions seeming OK

Tags: python, merge, permissions, shelve, gdbm

I'm working with shelve in python 2.7.6 for caching calculations, and I've ran into the issue described [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35771816/4038337) for shelve files produced by me and implemented the [suggested solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35782184/4038337) in a function that merges a file `other` into the file `target`:

```
... # target and other are strings
# Loads the gdbm module, as suggested
mod = __import__("gdbm")
# Open target for modifications
tar = shelve.Shelf(mod.open(target, 'c', 0666)) # THROWS EXCEPTION
# Open other for reading
oth  = shelve.Shelf(mod.open(other, 'r'))
...
```

The two files are *owned by me*, are recorded in a *local filesystem* and have posix permissions set to `0666`, or, equivalently, `-rw-rw-rw-` in my Linux Mint box, so that *the obvious checks have been performed*:

```
$ ls -l
-rw-rw-rw- 1 myusr mygrp 11694080 Sep 17 21:24 cache
-rw-rw-rw- 1 myusr mygrp 12189696 Sep 17 21:23 cache.0
```

Here, `cache` is the `target`, and `cache.0` is the `other` file. The current working directory is owned by me and has permissions `0775`, and I can create files with `touch`, `cp`, etc., at will with no problems, and I've even set my `umask` to `0000`, so new files are created with `0666`, or, equivalently, `-rw-rw-rw-` permissions.

I've even matched the actual file permissions with the permissions in the gdbm.open() call, according to its [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/gdbm.html#gdbm.open); however, to no avail.

**Update**: By running the python code with `sudo`, i.e., with superuser privileges, the error occurs on the *same line*; however with a different message: `gdbm error: Bad magic number`! This is very strange as the very point of using a (seemingly) lower-level module (`gdbm` as opposed to `shelve`) was precisely bypassing database type detection.

**Update #2**: Running `python whichdb.py` on the files returns `dbhash`; however, changing the module to the `dbhash` on the loading code still gives the following errors:

```
bsddb.db.DBAccessError: (13, 'Permission denied')
```

when running as user, but

```
bsddb.db.DBInvalidArgError: (22, 'Invalid argument -- BDB0210 ././merge-cache.py: metadata page checksum error')
```

when running with sudo; `merge-cache.py` is my code's name.

This new error is discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15958917/4038337), in connection with python version, but (i) my python version is different than the one in that post, and (ii) files are created and later read with the *same* version of python.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15577654/4038337) indicates `shelve` gets "wasted" with large sets, but the problem I'm reporting occurs with smaller databases as well.

**Question:** How can I open these shelve files using python-2.7.6? (upgrading python is not an option).